# Quickblox: prevent user from creating account

Tags: android, ios, security, quickblox

Currently, as per sample app of quickblox, Account key, Service Key and Service secret is stored in app itself.

My concern is that anybody can easily reverse engineer an app to get these secrets and create any number of fake account to troll other users (or even delete accounts?).

Alternatively, even if I generate session token on server, a user can get hold of this token and (as per my understanding) achieve the same thing as above.

What I want is to give user just enough information to login with his server generated credentials and send/receive messages.

Is there a way to achieve this? Maybe something like creating a session on server which allows only login and chat.

Answer (score 0):

The right way is to obfuscate your Account key, Service Key and Service secret values

there are a lot of ways to do it, also ProGuard can help with this

You also can create a session token on a server side and pass this token to your app by some way, for example to have another backend with such API, so end user will request a token from that API and next just use it withiut storing any sensetive data inside an app

Comment: Obfuscation will just make it a bit more difficult to get Account secrets. Regarding the session token from server, it will sure prevent anyone from getting Account secrets but, the token can be used to do everything we can do with Account secrets. So, again, it just makes it a bit more difficult for anyone to disrupt the whole app. What I would like is to have my server generate a limited permission token which can only be used to login and chat, not create and delete accounts.